# Scala koan AboutExtractors.scala wrong?

Tags: scala

I am a bit confused about this koan in `AboutExtractors.scala`. This code is from
[https://bitbucket.org/dmarsh/scalakoansexercises/wiki/Home](https://bitbucket.org/dmarsh/scalakoansexercises/wiki/Home%20%22ScalaKoans)

```
koan("In this koan we use the unapply for pattern matching employee objects") {

class Employee(val firstName: String,
               val middleName: Option[String],
               val lastName: String)

object Employee {
  //factory methods, extractors, apply
  //Extractor: Create tokens that represent your object
  def unapply(x: Employee) =
    Some(x.lastName, x.middleName, x.firstName)
}

val singri = new Employee("Singri", None, "Keerthi")

val result = singri match {
  case Employee("Singri", None, x) => "Yay, Singri %s! with no middle name!".format(x)
  case Employee("Singri", Some(x), _) => "Yay, Singri with a middle name of %s".format(x)
  case _ => "I don't care, going on break"
}

result should be("I don't care, going on break")
}
```

Why is the line `case Employee("Singri", None, x) => "Yay, Singri %s! with no middle name!".format(x)` not called?

It seems to me that `Employee("Singri", None, "Keerthi")` matches `Employee("Singri", None, x)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extractor (incorrectly/inadvisably) changes the order of the class parameters, putting the last name first. As such `Employee(x, None, "Singri")` would match.